# operator overloading for a class template specialization

Tags: c++, gcc, operator-overloading, template-specialization

I got stuck with a confusing problem here and i couldnt find any solution so far:
The linker complains about a multiple definition of an overloaded non-member operator==.
Imagine the following situation:

```
template <class T>
struct MyPtr
{
  T* val;
  ...
}

template <class T> bool operator==(MyPtr<T> const & lhs, MyPtr<T> const & rhs)
{ return *lhs.val == *rhs.val; }
template <class T> bool operator==(MyPtr<T> const & lhs, T* const & rhs)
{ return *lhs.val == *rhs;}
```

So far so good, everything works like a charme, but as i tried to specialize my class to react to a char* in specific way things get weird:

```
template <>
struct MyPtr<char>
{
  char* val;
  ...
}

//Now each of these functions result in a multiple definition error of the Linker, 
//and i dont get why:
//bool operator== (MyPtr<char> const& lhs, MyPtr<char> const& rhs)
//{ return strcmp(lhs.val,rhs.val) == 0;}

//template <> bool operator==<char> (MyPtr<char> const& lhs, MyPtr<char> const& rhs)
//{ return strcmp(lhs.val,rhs.val) == 0;}
```

So what am i doing wrong here? The ordering in my code is as it is written here. Moving these function definitions above the Class specialization result in the error:

```
Error : specialization of 'MyPtr<char>' after instantiation
Error : redefinition of 'class MyPtr<char>'
```

Please notice i have to use GCC 4.1.2 . I hope its not a compiler problem here... again...

Comment: What the hell `<char>` is doing in `operator==<char>`? And to avoid multiple definitions, use `inline` keyword.

Comment: When you say "each of these functions result in a multiple definition error", does that mean that you have both functions in your source, or only one of them?

Comment: That explicit template specialization is unlikely to ever be used, if you have a non-template function that takes identical arguments.

Comment: @aschepler This explicit template specialization is not only useless, but it does cause the linker problem here. The explicit specialization causes an instantiation, and that clashes with the non-template function.

Comment: Its there because its a function template specialization. See http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm for more information @VladLazarenko

Comment: Only one of them should be used at once, i added both, because they both didnt work. anyways the problem was caused because of the fact its function definition in a hpp file which needs to be inlined.

Comment: This compiles fine with gcc 4.7 and msvc 10. With both compilers the non-template version of the function is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A function definition should only appear in a header file if:

- It has been declared with the `inline` keyword, OR
- It is defined within a class definition, OR
- It involves at least one template parameter

(Those are among the cases where the multiple-identical-definitions version of ODR applies.)

So `inline` is not usually required with template functions.  But an explicit specialization doesn't actually have any template parameters, so you should mark it `inline` if you want it in the header file.

Comment: Oh well, after all these templates editing within hpp files i totally forgot that. Shame on me :-D
inlining the non-template version now does the trink

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't this

```
template <> bool operator==<char> (MyPtr<char> const& lhs, MyPtr<char> const& rhs)
{ return strcmp(lhs.val,rhs.val) == 0;}
```

be

```
template <> bool operator==<char> (MyPtr<char> const& lhs, char* const& rhs)
{ return strcmp(lhs.val,rhs) == 0;}
```

?

Thanks to jogojapan for the corrections

Comment: No, both of them are each one ways to define a operator. the first is a direct overload, while the second is a template function specialization. both of them try to achieve the same goal. I did not add specialized version for the second operator, as it does not add anything new to the question.

Comment: @PhilippMichalski Steven is right nevertheless. The point is that the second argument of the second version should be `char * const &`, not `MyPtr<char> const &`, because otherwise the two signatures are identical, which causes the redefinition error.

Comment: @StevenMaitlall The second argument of `strcmp` in the second version should be changed from `rhs.val` to `rhs`, too.

Comment: it was never meant to use both at once anyways. so i edited the question to reflect this